# more and less button with textview or label

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview

hi i want a `textview` or `label` with see more and less functionality. i tried with `label` and successfully got result as:

[image]

but if text will increase it `button` more will look like :

[image]

and in some conditions it will look :

[image]

i am trying to set `button` will automatically set according to text.can anyone suggest me better way to got this.

Comment: http://ilya.puchka.me/custom-uitextview-in-swift/

Comment: @adolfosrs how to use it in table view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `UILabel` than you can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) in that you can set clickable text.

Append your string "see more" or "less functionality" with label text and make it clickable.

Answer (score 0):

So there is my simple code that create label with [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) to implement 'more...' and 'less...' functionality for label:

```
- (void) setupStoreTitleLabel {
    self.titleLabel.delegate = self;
    [self.titleLabel setText:self.card.name];

    self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    NSAttributedString *showMore = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" more..." attributes:@{
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor],
        NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12],
        NSLinkAttributeName : [NSURL URLWithString:@"more..."]
        }];

    [self.titleLabel setAttributedTruncationToken:showMore];
}

#pragma mark - TTTAttributedLabelDelegate

- (void)attributedLabel:(__unused TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSLog(@"%@ pressed", url);
    if ([[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"more..."]) {
        self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 99;

        NSString *cardNameWithLess = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.card.name, @" less..."];
        [self.titleLabel setText:cardNameWithLess afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
            //code
            NSRange linkRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@" less..." options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blueColor] range:linkRange];
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] range:linkRange];
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"less..."] range:linkRange];

            return mutableAttributedString;
            }];
    } else {
        self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        NSAttributedString *showMore = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" more..." attributes:@{
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor],
            NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12],
            NSLinkAttributeName : [NSURL URLWithString:@"more..."]
            }];

        [self.titleLabel setAttributedTruncationToken:showMore];
        [self.titleLabel setText:self.card.name];
    }
}
```